# How not to rotate the image only the border around the image?

Tags: html, css

I am working on my project and I have added the image with border. I am rotating the border on hover but the problem is that, the image is also rotating.

```css
#circle1 {
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 6px solid #337AB7;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(50deg);
  transition: linear 2s;
}

#circle1 .elementor-widget-container {
  transform: rotate(-50deg);
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: linear 2s;
}

#circle1:hover {
  transform: rotate(410deg);
  transition: linear 2s;
}

#circle1 .elementor-widget-container:hover {
  transform: rotate(-410deg);
  transition: linear 2s;
}

#circle1 img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle1">
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <div class="elementor-image">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/WkdnS0f/BIcon-1.png" class="attachment-large size-large">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this, on hover image is also rotating but I dont want to rotate the image, only border should rotate.

Just hover to the image frequently, you will see image is also rotating.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this selector

```
#circle1 .elementor-widget-container:hover
```

to

```
#circle1:hover .elementor-widget-container
```

```css
#circle1 {
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 6px solid #337AB7;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(50deg);
  transition: linear 2s;
}

#circle1 .elementor-widget-container {
  transform: rotate(-50deg);
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: linear 2s;
}

#circle1:hover {
  transform: rotate(410deg);
  transition: linear 2s;
}

#circle1:hover .elementor-widget-container {
  transform: rotate(-410deg);
  transition: linear 2s;
}

#circle1 img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle1">
  <div class="elementor-widget-container">
    <div class="elementor-image">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/WkdnS0f/BIcon-1.png" class="attachment-large size-large">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could make both your HTML and CSS much simpler by using a pseudo element.

```css
#circle1 {
  position: relative;
}

#circle1::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 6px solid #337AB7;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  transform: rotate(50deg);
  transition: linear 2s;
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;
}

#circle1:hover::after {
  transform: rotate(410deg);
  transition: linear 2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle1">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/WkdnS0f/BIcon-1.png" class="attachment-large size-large">
</div>
```